# Running Jest with Apollo Server fails global.fetch undefined

Tags: graphql, jestjs, apollo, babel-jest

My team is going through the task of updating our projects. We have updated Jest and Apollo to the latest version. Running into an issue where we are doing integration testing with Apollo/GraphQL and getting errors stated below:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

  4 | 
  5 | import { createTestClient } from 'apollo-server-testing';
> 6 | import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-express";
    | ^
  7 | 
  8 | import schemaString from './../../schema/schema-string.mjs';
  9 | import resolvers from '../../../resolvers/query-resolvers.mjs';

  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/apollo-server-env/src/index.browser.js:6:15)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/apollo-server-core/src/index.ts:1:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/apollo-server-express/src/index.ts:1:1)
```

Digging into it, seems Apollo polyfils on the global property is not being set. Unsure how to solve this and couldn't find anything online as of yet. We also updated Babel but I don't feel it has anything to do with that unless it's a compiling issue. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Node doesn't have a global fetch method built in. You will need to polyfill it yourself. There are packages that can assist with this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-fetch-mock